# How to Pass A List of Key Value Pairs as a Parameter to a Cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

I am trying to pass a list of tags as a parameter to the `SSM` parameter store resource (`Cloudformation` template). I am running into the following error message:
`Template error: every Fn::Split object requires two parameters`.

1. A string delimiter
2. A string to be split or a function that returns a string to be
   split.

And here is the code below:

```yaml
LinuxCWConfigSSMParameter:
  Type: "AWS::SSM::Parameter"
  Properties:
    Name: !Ref LinuxSSMParameterName
    Tags: !Split [",", !Ref LinuxSSMParameterTags]
    Type: "String"
    Value: |
      {
        "agent": {
          "metrics_collection_interval": 60
        },
        "metrics": {
          "metrics_collected": {
            "mem": {
              "measurement": [
                {"name": "mem_active", "rename": "MemoryActive"},
                {"name": "mem_available", "rename": "MemoryAvailable"},
                {"name": "mem_available_percent", "rename": "%MemoryAvailable"},
                {"name": "mem_buffered", "rename": "MemoryBuffered"},
                {"name": "mem_cached", "rename": "MemoryCached"},
                {"name": "mem_free", "rename": "MemoryFree"},
                {"name": "mem_inactive", "rename": "MemoryInactive"},
                {"name": "mem_total", "rename": "MemoryTotal"},
                {"name": "mem_used", "rename": "MemoryUsed"},
                {"name": "mem_used_percent", "rename": "%MemoryUsed"}
              ]
            }
          },
          "append_dimensions": {
            "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}"
          }
        }
      }
```